# what 's the difference between x[1] and x[[1]] in list of list

Tags: r, list

```
x <- list(a=list(1, 2, 3), b=list(4, 5, 6), c=list(7, 8, 9))
```

then `class(x[1])` and `class(x[[1]])` both show :

> [1] "list"

then `x[[1]][[3]]` output:

> [1] 3

however, `x[1][[3]]` output:

> Error in x[1][[3]] : subscript out of bounds

So, why x[1][[3]] doesn't work? in my opinion, you can use [[ to subset the element of a list.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777567/is-there-a-logical-way-to-think-about-list-indexing/36815401#36815401) and the links for some commentary. `x[[1]][[3]]` or `x[[c(1, 3)]]` reference the third element of the first list element. `x[1]` returns a list element of length 1, so the second `[[3]]` has no third element to extract.

Comment: thank you. yes, x[1] is still a list of list and with length of 1.