# lapply , sapply, and apply function in simple context

Tags: r

Running this code in R :

```
pr <- function(x) {
  x
}

lapply(c("a" , "b") , pr)

sapply(c("a" , "b") , pr)

apply(c("a" , "b") , pr)
```

returns :

```
> pr <- function(x) {
+   x
+ }
> 
> lapply(c("a" , "b") , pr)
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "b"

> 
> sapply(c("a" , "b") , pr)
  a   b 
"a" "b" 
> 
> apply(c("a" , "b") , pr)
Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
```

Here is my understanding of returns values of `lapply` , `sapply` , `apply` in above context:

`lapply` returns a list , is this signified by `[[1]]`?

`sapply` returns a vector but why are vector dimensions `[1]` not returned in response?

`apply` returns an error , why is this occurring?

Comment: The `apply` needs a `MARGIN` argument.  In this case it is 2.  BTW, it won't even work here because it is for `data.frame` or `matrix` i.e. `apply(t(c("a" , "b")) , 2, pr)`

Comment: I highly recommend the following read "Advanced R"  (functionals chapter) by Hadley Wickham: [http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html). And also have a look at the standard documentation of the functions in R (and the examples) :-)

Comment: May I suggest reading the documentation of these functions?

Comment: I removed any mention of Rstudio as this question has nothing to do with the IDE. It is solely a question about R. (R and Rstudio are independent pieces of software).

Answer (score 3):

The `lapply/sapply` loops through each element i.e. in this case each element of the `vector` (`c('a', 'b')`).  If it is a data.frame, the columns will be the looped and a `matrix` is a `vector` with dimensions, therefore, each element will be looped and the function is applied.  The output returned is a `list` for `lapply` and `sapply` here it is a `vector`, but it depends on the argument `simplify`.  By default it is `simplify = TRUE`, so if the lengths of the output elements are same, it returns a `vector`.

With `apply`, we needs a `MARGIN` argument.  The `MARGIN`s are there for `data.frame` or `matrix`.  Suppose, if we convert the `vector` to a `matrix`, then with `MARGIN` it works

```
apply(t(c("a" , "b")) , 2, pr)
```

If it is a single column matrix, use the `MARGIN=1`

```
apply(matrix(c('a', 'b')), 1, pr)
```

It could return a `list`, `vector` etc depending on the length of the output element.  Here, it is just returning the values.  So, it is a `vector`

Comment: sapply returns a vector but why are vector dimensions [1] not returned in response, is this some quirk of rstudio ?

Comment: @blue-sky  As mentioned, the default for `sapply` is `simplify = TRUE`

Comment: thanks but would have thought using sapply(c("a" , "b"), pr, simplify = FALSE) should return [1] "a" "b" . What is significance of [[1]] ?

Comment: @blue-sky As you noted, it is returning a `list` because you don't want to simplify it to a vector.  The significance of `[[1]]` is that it subsets the first list element to give 'a'

Comment: @blue-sky Read the documentation on `?[` It contains very useful information that should help to clarify the differences between lists and vectors. Maybe also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777567/is-there-a-logical-way-to-think-about-list-indexing/36815401).